# How to convert string to array using np.where

Tags: pandas

```
Male_Female = users[['occupation','gender','age']]
Male_Female
```

Output

```
occupation  gender  age
0   technician  M   24
1   other   F   53
2   writer  M   23
3   technician  M   24
4   other   F   33
```

I need to convert the string from  `M=1, F=0`

`Male_Female_numeric = Male_Female(np.where((users['gender'] == 'M'), 1, 0))`
`Male_Female_numeric`

I got error

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Disclaimer: I got the output with the below code

```
def gender_to_numeric(x):
    if x == 'M':
        return 1
    if x == 'F':
        return 0
```

`users['gender_n'] = users['gender'].apply(gender_to_numeric)`

How to achieve the same output using `np.where`

Comment: just use: `users['gender_n']=np.where((users['gender'] == 'M'), 1, 0)`

Comment: @anky_91 then i will get array([1, 0, 1, 1, ....]]

Comment: yes, assign back to the original frame as a series. see my comment above

Comment: also you can use: `users['gender_n']=users['gender_n'].eq('Male').astype(int)`

Comment: @anky_91  `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` got above error

Comment: that is because the Male_Female df is referred from the original df. use `Male_Female = users[['occupation','gender','age']].copy()` first and then `Male_Female['gender_n']=np.where((Male_Female['gender'] == 'M'), 1, 0)` , read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)